# Visual C++ 2010 and Qt (moc etc)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and I know there's the Qt VS Add-In. However I've chosen to not use it as according to an announcement by Nokia they will not release any further versions of it. So now would be a good time to change work practises.

I'm looking for a way to automatically call moc.exe on class files that need to be moc'ed, and for the moc'ed files to be compiled as well. I'll probably do this for the resource/ui compilers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-in is mainly useful to import *.pro* files to VS projects, after that you do not really need the add-in (unless for making it easier to change between different Qt versions). 
Just make sure to define *QTDIR* in a project property page (*.vsprops*) as *UserMacro* and have it exported to the environment, then you can use it for *$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe* against Qt header files in the custom build step, similarly for UIs.

```
<UserMacro
    Name="QTDIR"
    Value="C:\Qt\4.6.3"
    PerformEnvironmentSet="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Qt's plugin simply creates Visual Studio build rules files - these are 'normal' xml files and anything can use them.

There were a series of [add-in VS macros](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Paul%27s_autoBuild%3a_Qt4_with_Visual_Studio) before the visual studio plugin became available.